# Preprocessing failed for performance counters zabbix, MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent, visualization

I've connected my MSSQL server to zabbix via ODBC.

I'm receiving results for some items but for other items errors are returned:

```
Preprocessing failed for: [{"object_name":"SQLServer:Buffer Manager","cntr_value":"4947","counter_name":"Background writer ...
1. Failed: cannot extract value from json by path "$[?(@.counter_name=='BufferCacheHitRatio')].cntr_value.first()": no data matches the specified path
```

[image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJsdi.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJsdi.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhrNL.png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhrNL.png%22)

For these 3 metrics "[metrics concerned][2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stMjX.png"

aka:
`CacheHitRatio, WorktablesFromCacheRatio and BufferCacheHitRatio`, which are being pulled with the item: `MSSQL: Get performance counters`
this item uses this SQL Request to pull the performance counter metrics:

```
SELECT object_name,
  counter_name,
  instance_name,
  cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
UNION SELECT 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename AS object_name,
  'Version' AS counter_name,
  @@version AS instance_name,
  0 AS cntr_value
UNION SELECT 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename AS object_name,
  'Uptime' AS counter_name,
  '' AS instance_name,
  DATEDIFF(second, sqlserver_start_time, GETDATE()) AS cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
UNION SELECT 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Databases' AS object_name,
  'State' AS counter_name,
  name AS instance_name,
  state AS cntr_value
FROM sys.databases
UNION SELECT a.object_name,
  'BufferCacheHitRatio' AS counter_name,
  '' AS instance_name,
  cast(a.cntr_value * ISNULL((100.0 / NULLIF(b.cntr_value,0)),0) AS dec(3, 0)) AS cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters a
JOIN (
  SELECT cntr_value,
    OBJECT_NAME
  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
  WHERE counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio base'
    AND OBJECT_NAME = 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Buffer Manager'
) b
  ON a.OBJECT_NAME = b.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE a.counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio'
  AND a.OBJECT_NAME = 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Buffer Manager'
UNION SELECT a.object_name,
  'WorktablesFromCacheRatio' AS counter_name,
  '' AS instance_name,
  cast(a.cntr_value * ISNULL((100.0 / NULLIF(b.cntr_value,0)),0) AS dec(3, 0)) AS cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters a
JOIN (
  SELECT cntr_value,
    OBJECT_NAME
  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
  WHERE counter_name = 'Worktables From Cache Base'
    AND OBJECT_NAME = 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Access Methods'
) b
  ON a.OBJECT_NAME = b.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE a.counter_name = 'Worktables From Cache Ratio'
  AND a.OBJECT_NAME = 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Access Methods'
UNION SELECT a.object_name,
  'CacheHitRatio' AS counter_name,
  '_Total' AS instance_name,
  cast(a.cntr_value * ISNULL((100.0 / NULLIF(b.cntr_value,0)),0) AS dec(3, 0)) AS cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters a
JOIN (
  SELECT cntr_value,
    OBJECT_NAME
  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
  WHERE counter_name = 'Cache Hit Ratio base'
    AND OBJECT_NAME = 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Plan Cache'
    AND instance_name = '_Total'
) b
  ON a.OBJECT_NAME = b.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE a.counter_name = 'Cache Hit Ratio'
  AND a.OBJECT_NAME = 'MSSQL$' + @@servicename + ':Plan Cache'
  AND instance_name = '_Total'
```

I have no clue what's wrong, note that when i log into my user with ODBC and isql and try to get one of those counter metrics such as the hit ratio one, I'm successful.
[result of isqli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJsdi.png)

so the issue is definitely not from the user. I also enabled the Pollers for ODBC inside the zabbix config file and set it to 5 then restarted zabbix. I don't know what could be the issue, any help would be appreciated. The json preprocessing step being used in zabbix's item is "`$[?(@.counter_name=='BufferCacheHitRatio')].cntr_value.first()"`